# How to create a Tools menu on the Network Admin dashboard from a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, dashboard

I'm coding a plugin. I want to put a Tools menu item on the Network Admin dashboard when the plugin is installed on a multisite WordPress instance.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to put a Tools menu item on the Network Admin dashboard

If you meant under the core top-level "Dashboard" menu as seen on the following screenshot, then you can use the [`network_admin_menu` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/network_admin_menu/) along with [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) to add your menu item.

[image: Preview image]

Or if you wanted a *top-level menu* like the following, then use the same hook as above, but use [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) to add the menu, and then use `add_submenu_page()` to add menu items (i.e. submenus) to that top-level menu.

[image: Preview image]

### Full Working Example

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 391799
 * Description: Network Admin custom "Tools" menus
 * Version: 1.0
 */

// Adds the custom Network Admin menus.
add_action( 'network_admin_menu', 'wpse_391799_add_network_admin_menus' );
function wpse_391799_add_network_admin_menus() {
    add_submenu_page( 'index.php',      // parent slug or file name of a standard WordPress admin page
        'My Tools Page',                // menu page title
        'My Tools (Submenu)',           // menu title
        'manage_network',               // user capability required to access the menu (and its page)
        'my-tools-page',                // menu slug that's used with the "page" query, e.g. ?page=menu-slug
        'wpse_391799_render_tools_page' // the function which outputs the page content
    );

    add_menu_page( 'My Tools Page',      // menu page title
        'My Tools (Top-Level)',          // menu title
        'manage_network',                // user capability required to access the menu (and its page)
        'my-tools-page2',                // menu slug to that's with the "page" query, e.g. ?page=menu-slug
        'wpse_391799_render_tools_page', // the function which outputs the page content
        'dashicons-admin-tools',         // menu icon (in this case, I'm using a Dashicons icon's CSS class)
        24                               // menu position; 24 would place the menu above the "Settings" menu
    );

    add_submenu_page( 'my-tools-page2',
        'My Tools Submenu Page',
        'My Tools Submenu',
        'manage_network',
        'my-tools-submenu-page',
        'wpse_391799_render_tools_submenu_page'
    );
}

// Outputs the content for the "My Tools (Submenu)" and "My Tools (Top-Level)" pages.
function wpse_391799_render_tools_page() {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap my-tools-parent">
            <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
            <p>Foo bar. Bla bla. Your content here.</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}

// Outputs the content for the "My Tools Submenu" page.
function wpse_391799_render_tools_submenu_page() {
    ?>
        <div class="wrap my-tools-submenu">
            <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
            <p>Foo bar. Bla bla. Your content here.</p>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful indeed.

Comment: Glad it helped :) And sorry, one of the PHP comments contained `menu slug to that's with` which should actually be `menu slug that's used with`... :p

Answer (score -1):

With this code on functions.php we make a dashboard tab with 3 pages (that should be created on the theme path in this case inside a folder called inc).
On the plugin should be something very similar but with the code on the plugin files.

if a explanation is needed it, only in a few hours when I arrive home. thanks.

```php
function tc_editor(){
  add_menu_page('tiago\'s', 'Procamiao', 'manage_options', 'editor_tiagos', 'tc_definicoes', home_url().'/wp-content/themes/procamiao/inc/mini_logo.png', 4);
  add_submenu_page('editor_tiagos', 'separador_definicoes', 'Definições', 'manage_options', 'editor_tiagos');
  add_submenu_page('editor_tiagos', 'separador_banners', 'Banners', 'manage_options','editor_banners', 'tc_banners');
  add_submenu_page('editor_tiagos', 'separador_default', 'Default', 'manage_options','editor_tabelas', 'tc_default');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'tc_editor');

function tc_definicoes(){require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'inc/definicoes.php';}
function tc_banners(){require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'inc/banners.php';}
function tc_default(){require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'inc/default.php';}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the network dashboard as the OP asked.